# Trying to delete an entry

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneBook {
    
    private Address[] addresses;
    private String[] phoneNumbers;
    private Person[] people;
    public static String menu = ("Please Make A selection Below: \n1 - Add new Record"
            + " \n2 - Delete Record \n3 - Find Record By First Name "
            + "\n3 - Find Record By Telephone Number "
            + "\n4 - Find Record By First Name "
            + "\n5 - Find Record By Last Name"
            + "\n6 - Update a Record"
            + "\n7 - Exit");
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner intScan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    
            // printing menu 
                System.out.println(menu);
                //boolean quit = false;
                Entry[] entry1 = new Entry[50];
                int z = 0;
                int selection;
                do {
                // next user input (of integer type) will be stored in the variable selection
                selection = intScan.nextInt();
                switch (selection) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Please enter a new record as John Michael West Doe, 574 Pole ave, St. Peter, MO, 63303, 3142752000");
    
                    // method to add that input to entry 
                        
                        String input = scanner.nextLine();
                        
                        Entry entry = addEntry(input);
                        entry1[z] = entry;
                        z++;
                        
                        System.out.println("Another entry?");
                        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                        char cont = scan.next().charAt(0);
                        while(cont == 'y') {
                            System.out.println("Please enter a new record as John Michael West Doe, 574 Pole ave, St. Peter, MO, 63303, 3142752000");
                            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                            entry = addEntry(input);
                            entry1[z] = entry;
                            z++;
                            
                            cont = scan.next().charAt(0);
                        }
                        System.out.println(menu);
                        break;
                        
                        // create an array - of 100 spaces... 
                        
                        // add entry into array - for whatever number z is.... 
                        // z++ -
                        
                        // make the method - as if I was to write it in the main method
                        // instead of having that every time - 
                        // method just to create a class... 
                    
                    
                case 2: 
                    selection = intScan.nextInt();
                    // method to delete record - remove 
                    System.out.println("What record do you want to delete?");
                    //displayEntry(0, entry1);
                    String input2 = scanner.nextLine();
                    
                    
                    Entry[] entry2 = deleteEntry(entry1, input2);
                    
                    
                    // System.out.println("What now? ");
                     int num = scanner.nextInt();
                    
                    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    char cont2 = scan2.next().charAt(0);
                    while(cont2 == 'y') {
                        System.out.println("What else would you like to delete?");
                        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                        
        
                        
                        System.out.println("Another entry?");
                        cont = scan2.next().charAt(0);
                    }
                    System.out.println(menu);
                    break;
                    
                
                case 3:
                    // search by telephone number
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    // find record by first name
                    break;
                case 5: 
                    // find record by last name
                    break;
                case 6: 
                    // update a record 
                    break;
                case 7:
                    //quit = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid");
                    
                    
                }
                
            } while(selection != 7);
}
    

    
    public static Entry addEntry(String input) {
        String[] inputs = input.split(",");
        String name, street, city, state, zipCode, phoneNumber;
        
        name = "";
        street = "";
        city = "";
        state = "";
        zipCode = "";
        phoneNumber = "";
        
        name = inputs[0];
        street = inputs[1].trim();
        city = inputs[2].trim();
        state = inputs[3].trim();
        zipCode = inputs[4].trim();
        phoneNumber = inputs[5].trim();
        
        Name newName = createName(name);
        Address address = createAddress(street, city, state, zipCode);
        Phone phone = createPhone(phoneNumber);
        
        Entry entry = new Entry(newName, address, phone);
        return entry;   
    }
    
     //method for deleting an entry
    public static Entry[] deleteEntry(Entry[] entry, String input2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
            if (entry[i].equals(input2)) {
                entry[i] = null;
                break;
            }
        }
        return entry;
    }
    
    
    
     //method for displaying entry
    public static void displayEntry(int y, Entry[] entry) {
        String fName = (String) entry[y].getName().getFirstName();
        String mName = (String) entry[y].getName().getMiddleName();
        String lName = (String) entry[y].getName().getLastName();
        String name = fName + " " + mName + " " + lName;
        String street = (String) entry[y].getAddress().getStreet();
        String city = (String) entry[y].getAddress().getCity();
        String state = (String) entry[y].getAddress().getState();
        String zipCode = (String) entry[y].getAddress().getZipCode();
        String address = street + " " + city + " " + state + " " + zipCode;
        String area = (String) entry[y].getPhone().getArea();
        String prefix = (String) entry[y].getPhone().getPrefix();
        String line = (String) entry[y].getPhone().getLine();
        String phone = "(" + area + ")" + "-" + prefix + "-" + line;
        System.out.println( fName + " " + mName + " " + lName);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Address: " + address);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Phone: " + phone);
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    // method to create name based off the first 3 words from the scanner
    
    public static Name createName(String name) {
        String fName, mName, lName;
        fName = "";
        mName = "";
        lName = "";
        
        String[] names = name.split(" ");
        
             fName = names[0];
             lName = names[names.length-1];
            
            for(int i =1; i < names.length - 1; i++) {
                mName = mName  + names[i];
                if (i != names.length-1) {
                    mName += "";
                }
            }
            // if to see if it's a middle name 
            // put into an array of entries.... entry[0] - breaks out name, address, phone number
            
        
        
        Name name1 = new Name(fName, mName, lName);
        return name1;
    }
    
    // method to create address 
    
    public static Address createAddress(String street, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        Address address1 = new Address(street, city, state, zipCode);
        return address1;
    }
    
    // method to create a phone based off the user input
    public static Phone createPhone(String input) {
        String area, prefix, line;
        
        area = input.substring(0, 3);
        prefix = input.substring(3, 6);
        line = input.substring(6);
        
        Phone phone1 = new Phone(area, prefix, line);
        return phone1;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    // find record by telephone number: 
    
    
    // write down process - on white board - 
    
    
}
// make methods in main program
        
        
        // if 1 selected: 
        // Please enter new record a : John Michael West Doe, 574 Pole ave, St. Peter, MO, 63303, 3142752000
        
        
        //**Show all records in asc order *note you will need to research sorting on an array.
```

I'm not sure why it won't let me delete a record after I input it.

```
Entry[] entry2 = deleteEntry(entry1, input2);
```

input 2 is the selection from the scanner and entry1 is the array that I created to store the records in.
There's a hangup somewhere because I receive these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PhoneBook.deleteEntry(PhoneBook.java:152)
    at PhoneBook.main(PhoneBook.java:76)
```

I know in line 152, I'm trying to compare a string to an Entry[] object, but I don't know another way to pass in the record that I want deleted for that method.

I'm trying to just use arrays and no Lists or anything.

Comment: What is null on that line?

Comment: You also don't appear to be handling the end-of-line tokens with the Scanner correctly. If this were my problem, I'd use my debugger to see exactly what is happening before the error is thrown and when it is thrown.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's when I input 0 and press enter, it's saying that it's null.. but there was supposed to be a record in Entry[] entry1[0] - I'm trying to remove

Comment: Only you have the full code, so use it to your advantage. Again, use your debugger to see why something is null that you don't expect to be null. And again, make sure that you are handling the end-of-line tokens correctly with your Scanner. Please look at [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo) to see what I'm talking about.